# Is there a need of testing the view in JavaScript MVC frameworks

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, unit-testing, mvp

I see a lot questions here on SO where people try to test Backbone apps where the  test belongs to the DOM. Coming from GWT, where most of the time the view is not tested, I wonder if there is really a need to this with JavaScript MVC frameworks. Is this a problem depends on the architecture of backbone, which isn't really a passive view like GWT.

- I wonder how this will be solved in other languages like ruby or php. Does the people test the view there?
- Is there a need of unit test with real DOM elements?
- Is there a good way to mock out the DOM in JavaScript?
- Are there any JavaScript frameworks that make it easier to test only the controller/presenter

Answer (score 0):

I think a reasonably good approach to testing the actual UI of a web application would be to use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to do proper integration testing.

Creating tests for the DOM/view parts of it could otherwise easily lead to brittle tests, or tests that don't really test much at all, especially if you consider databinding does much of the work.